# Failed to add the foreign key constraint, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I have this error on PopSQL :

> Error: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'etape__ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'etapexprojet_'
> Error Code: ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT

This is my code, i'm only creating tables and it has a problem in the "Etape_" part, i really, don't know why

I'm really, really new to SQL. Like... this is my first time doing this

```
--Client
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.client_ (
    idClient INT PRIMARY KEY,
    nomClient VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    adresse VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    telephone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    adresseCourriel VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );

--Employés
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.Employe_ (
    idEmploye INT PRIMARY KEY,
    nomEmploye VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    adresse VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    telephone VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    adresseCourriel VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );

 --Projet
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.Projet_ (
      idProjet INT PRIMARY KEY, 
      idClient INT ,
      nomProjet VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
      dateDebut DATE NOT NULL ,
      dateFin DATE,
      idResponsable INT NOT NULL ,
      FOREIGN KEY (idClient ) REFERENCES jegere.Client_ (idClient ),
      FOREIGN KEY (idResponsable ) REFERENCES jegere.Employe_ (idEmploye )
);

--RessourcesProjet
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.RessourcesProjet_ (
    idProjet INT NOT NULL,
    idEmploye INT NOT NULL,
    nbrHeure INT NOT NULL,
    PrixHeure FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idProjet, idEmploye),
    FOREIGN KEY(idProjet) REFERENCES projet_(idProjet),
    FOREIGN KEY(idEmploye) REFERENCES employe_(idEmploye)
);

--Etape X Projet
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.EtapexProjet_ (
    idEtape INT NOT NULL,
    idProjet INT NOT NULL,
    dateDebut DATE NOT NULL ,
    dateFin DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(idProjet, idEtape),
    FOREIGN KEY(idProjet) REFERENCES projet_(idProjet)
);

--Etapes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.Etape_ (
    idEtape INT,
    nomEtape VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Livrable VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idEtape),
    FOREIGN KEY(idEtape) REFERENCES etapexprojet_(idEtape)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The referenced column in a foreign key needs to be indexed, so you need to add an index on the `idEtape` column in `etapexprojet`:

```
--Etape X Projet
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jegere.EtapexProjet_ (
    idEtape INT NOT NULL,
    idProjet INT NOT NULL,
    dateDebut DATE NOT NULL ,
    dateFin DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(idProjet, idEtape),
    INDEX (idEtape),
    FOREIGN KEY(idProjet) REFERENCES projet_(idProjet)
);
```

Having it as part of the primary key isn't sufficient. A prefix of an index is also an index, but `idEtape` is a later part of the primary key index, so it's not indexed by itself.

Another solution is to change the order of the primary key:

```
    PRIMARY KEY(idEtape, idProject),
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the column referenced by the foreign key should be a primary key or unique key. You don't want it to be non-unique. That means a row in the child table can reference _multiple_ rows in the parent table, and down that road lies madness.

Comment: @BillKarwin While that's the usual expectation, it's not required by MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I understand that InnoDB allows a foreign key to reference the leftmost column(s) of any key, but it creates weird edge cases that aren't defined in standard SQL. Like what if one of the foreign key is defined as cascading, and _one_ of the referenced parent rows is updated? Should the child row be changed or not? It's better to avoid the ambiguity by using traditional foreign key definitions, and reference only a primary/unique key.